# Protected php access

Tags: php, security

In my video game I want users to be able to publish/get map data from a MySQL server.
My problem is that I want to make it limited to make the program only be able to create/get levels, not being able to spam the hell out of the page and make loads of fake levels (by the php page)

I'm trying to prevent the number of fake requests, so that real users playing the game can only have real access to the PHP content, not people who want to spoil the experience.

I'm aware that I can do a simple check for a code, but what happens when that code is caught out? It's not really authentication, perhaps I could do a serial check, but the game won't require you to register online and make an account at all.

Comment: CAPTCHA, validation of levels before saving in DB?

Comment: What's your php code? Are you using any kind of api structure e.g. RESTFUL? @yabol I think captcha would be odd in a video game

Comment: First time I've seen the "Super Meat Boy made me do it" reason. How is a 'fake' level identified? Don't you just want to implement a user and group permissions security setup, with limits to how many or quickly something may be done by whoever is permitted? To a degree, if it's cracked open to the unwashed internet masses, you're in a possible spam situation.

Comment: Well not really because of Super Meat Boy, I was going to use PHP anyway, but really the game code will call the php script with certain arguments, for example:
`/script?action=create&level="LEVEL CODE HERE"&creator="username"`
People can access this from within the browser and create loads of levels from outside of the game.

Comment: Well, one request is like any other request. You need to define what is invalid and what isn't. This usually involves some form of *authentication*. Either the game needs to identify itself or users have to identify themselves to call those PHP methods. Otherwise you have no real handle to distinguish "valid" from "invalid". The details of this authentication process depend on your details.

Comment: You can do nothing and try Fail2Ban, if you don't want to add a user and permission system. Or use some type of message encryption with a signature to validate the request's origin and log a specific request's identifier, and then refuse requests that are received too quickly. Or, require requests to be accompanied by authenticated users and detect and ignore requests from a user who is repeatedly requesting new levels. I guess I don't really know what you're asking otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, I would recommend you using REST web services. I'm actually using [tonic](http://peej.github.com/tonic/) REST framework, or if you need something lightweight, [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) might be the right for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are scared of is that the php page will be web accessible so that anyone can have access to it. In which case I would use $_GET variables to secure the page and send data.

E.g to create a level:
http://www.example.com/create.php?key=hkjaSDFg45fgsdGDF&user=13542&map=underground&etc..

then in the create.php file it would look like

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['key'] && $_GET['key'] == hkjaSDFg45fgsdGDF){
  //check if user is allowed -- $_GET[user]
  if(userallowed($_GET['user'])){
    //create map
  }
}
```

This is only meant as an example, but if you do not want to go and create a fully fledged api then something like this would do the job

**ALWAYS VALIDATE DATA FIRST AND NEVER USE DIRECTLY FROM THE $_GET VARIBLE**

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have to accept that a malicious user will *always* be able to access that server and create those maps if they want. They have the game's code and thus can reverse-engineer it to undo anything you can think of, given time.

- Have the user create an account for your server. Here you can use some sort of captcha.
- Require registered / logged in user to submit a map
- Limit the number of maps a user can create per minute (Write your game code in a way that it does not affect your real users)
- Maybe limit the total number of maps a user can submit
- Use HTTPS if at all possible.